# converting a dataframe to a 2 column dataframe based on vaues

Tags: r, reshape

I am trying to convert a multi-column dataframe to a 2 column dataframe. Each row is a person (based on id in first col) with multiple attributes. How can I list each person and attribute in 2 columns?

Example:

```
 temp<-data.frame(V1 = c(1,2,3),V2 = c(4,5,6))
 row.names(temp)<-c("person1","person2","person3")
 temp
         V1 V2
 person1  1  4
 person2  2  5
 person3  3  6
 res<-data.frame(person=c("person1","person1","person2","person2","person3",
         "person3"),val= c(1,4,2,5,3,6))
 res
     person val
 1 person1   1
 2 person1   4
 3 person2   2
 4 person2   5
 5 person3   3
 6 person3   6
```

Comment: `library(reshape2) ; temp$id <- rownames(temp) ; melt(temp, "id")`

Comment: or `melt(as.matrix(temp))` or to get the format as shown in the expected `data.frame(person=row.names(temp)[row(temp)], val=c(t(temp)))`

Comment: Or, just use `reshape` from the base R.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, That worked perfectly, if you will post it as a solution I will accept it

Comment: What about @akruns solution? It seems much shorter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my comment converted to an answer per request

```
library(reshape2) 
temp$id <- rownames(temp) 
melt(temp, "id")
```

Or a simpler version by @akrun

```
melt(as.matrix(temp))
```

Answer (score 1):

hadley-solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

temp %>% 
   add_rownames() %>% 
   gather(col, val, -rowname) %>% 
   select(-col)
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution without needing extra packages:

```
> temp$person <- row.names(temp)
> row.names(temp) <- NULL
> temp
  V1 V2  person
1  1  4 person1
2  2  5 person2
3  3  6 person3

> reshape(data = temp,
+         varying = list(c("V1","V2")),
+         v.names = "val",
+         idvar = "person",
+         direction = "long")
           person time val
person1.1 person1    1   1
person2.1 person2    1   2
person3.1 person3    1   3
person1.2 person1    2   4
person2.2 person2    2   5
person3.2 person3    2   6
```